# Connect wi-fi via ADB

Tags: wifi, connect, adb

How to connect to wi-fi via ADB without root access?
Going to settings menu and keyevents isn't working for me.

Comment: I just made a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810593/how-to-connect-to-adb-via-wifi-with-a-convenient-bat-file/16810594#16810594

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it...

`1) adb kill-server`
`2) adb connect the-ip-of-your-device`

I connect even without connecting a usb-cable first, ALSO without Root. I hate rooting my devices

Working on Asus TF300